# JSF 2.0 validateRegex with own validator message

Tags: regex, jsf-2, message, validation, textinput

i am having a code similar to this:

```
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{managePasswordBean.forgotPasswordEmail}"
        validatorMessage="#{validate['constraints.email.notValidMessage']}"
        requiredMessage="#{validate['constraints.email.emptyMessage']}"
        validator="#{managePasswordBean.validateForgotPasswordEmail}"
        required="true">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$" />
</h:inputText>
```

The validator in the backing bean has its own validation message generated. but it is overwritten by the validatorMessage of the inputText tag.

My Question is: how can i define a custom validator message for the validateRegex tag? I don't want to remove the validatorMessage cause then JSF is displaying an own error message containing the regex pattern and so on -> which i dont find very pretty.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can change all the messages, but you can not have specific message for each component in your application.
Take a look at this :
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 13):

You can't define a separate `validatorMessage` for each individual validator. Best what you can do is to do the regex validation in your custom validator as well, so that you can remove the `validatorMessage`.

---

**Update**: since version 1.3, the [`<o:validator>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/validator) component of the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) allows you to set the validator message on a per-validator basis. Your particular case can then be solved as follows:

```
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{managePasswordBean.forgotPasswordEmail}"
        required="true" requiredMessage="#{validate['constraints.email.emptyMessage']}">
    <o:validator binding="#{managePasswordBean.validateForgotPasswordEmail}" message="#{validate['constraints.email.notValidMessage']}" />
    <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.RegularExpression" pattern="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$" message="Your new custom message here" />
</h:inputText>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: these days you would be *not* ready for world domination as long as you still validate email addresses based on Latin characters. See also [Email validation using regular expression in JSF 2 / PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875108/email-validation-using-regular-expression-in-jsf-2-primefaces/12824163#12824163).

Comment: Wow, Not being able to set a custom error message makes jsf validations less than useless! Code that is just Java spam, not worth the 2cents of hard drive space it occupies on my harddrive.

Comment: Omnifaces solution didn't work for me. Follow the showcase, but there are still the JSF validation message. Not a hint to my custom messages...

Comment: It's new since OmniFaces 1.3. Make sure that you've at least OmniFaces 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
You can write your custom messages in "validatorMessage"

```
 <h:form id="form">
        <h:outputLabel for="name">Name :</h:outputLabel>  
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{editStock.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Name field must not be empty" validatorMessage="Your name can have only Alphabets">  
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z]*$" />  
        </h:inputText><br/>  
        <h:message for="name" style="color:red" />
        <h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{stock.update(editStock)}" style="width: 80px;"></h:commandButton> 
 </h:form>
```