# Email validation using regular expression in JSF 2 / PrimeFaces

Tags: regex, jsf-2, primefaces, email-validation

I have an input field taking an email address:

```
<h:inputText value="#{register.user.email}" required="true" />
```

How can I validate the entered value as a valid email address using regex in JSF 2 / PrimeFaces?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is how:

Using it myself...

```
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{settingsBean.aFriendEmail}" required="true" label="Email" validatorMessage="#{settingsBean.aFriendEmail} is not valid">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
</h:inputText>
<p:message for="email" />
```

Daniel.

Comment: how to update the above regex to make the valid domains only : .com,.net, .org, .edu ?
also any ideas how to make this validation on focus lost ?

Comment: Here is how : `<f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.(com|net|org|edu)"/>`

Comment: Doesn't work for a completely valid email containing plus sign, like name+surname@domain.com.

Answer (score 53):

All regular expression attempts to validate the email format based on *Latin* characters are **broken**. They do not support [internationalized domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) which were available since May 2010. Yes, you read it right, non-Latin characters are since then allowed in domain names and thus also email addresses.

That are thus extremely a lot of possible characters to validate. Best is to just keep it simple. The following regex just validates the email format based on the occurrence of the `@` and `.` characters.

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="([^.@]+)(\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\.)+([^.@]+)" />
```

Again, this just validates the general email format, not whether the email itself is legit. One can still enter `aa@bb.cc` as address and pass the validation. No one regex can cover that. If the validity of the email address is that important, combine it with an authentication system. Just send some kind of an activation email with a callback link to the email address in question and let the user login by email address.

Comment: an email k092167@nu.edu.pk is a valid email yet it is not validated by this regex pattern still +1 for the application

Comment: @anas: Works for me. Perhaps you need double backslashes?

Comment: Yeah maybe double backslashes would do, i copy pasted your regex and tried but it didnt work for only this email.

Answer (score 10):

Here's my version and it works well :

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
```

And i made a demo [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/primefaces-jsf-email-validator-example/)

Answer (score 1):

This one supports unicode domain names in email:

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}.-]*(\.[\p{L}\p{M}]{2,})$" />
```

... and this one validates email only when email is entered (email is not required field in form):

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="(^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}.-]*(\.[\p{L}\p{M}]{2,})$)?" />
```

Comment: The second one was very useful for me when the email is not required (optional) in form

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:inputText id="email" required="true" label="email" size="40"
    requiredMessage="Please enter your email address."
    validatorMessage="Invalid email format"
    value="#{userBean.email}">

  <f:validateRegex
    pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />

</p:inputText>
<p:watermark for="email" value="Email Address *" />
<p:message for="email" />

<p:commandButton value="test" style="margin:20px"
    action="#{userBean.register}" ajax="false" />
```