# valid ( existing ) email address verification

Tags: java, validation, email

I have this registration page which works fine ,but for the email field I need to make sure that the email is correct and valid
1 : Correct
2 : Valid

for the correct email add i am using java script validation for maintaining
abc@def.com

well that is working fine

but my question is , Is there any web service or java API to make sure whether the mail ID actually is existing and registered
Like my mail id is : hussainABCD@gmail.com
this is actually a existing ID

but i may try hussain5555@gmail.com,hussain1111@gmail.com,hussain8888@gmail.com,

these will pass the java script validation but are not existing in reality

do we have any way to make sure that the mail id exists ??

Comment: Like everyone else, just send a mail with an activation link. Or like Stack Overflow, use OpenID.

Comment: By the way, be careful with email format validation, you seem to be restricting Latin characters only. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1931322 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824163

Comment: @BalusC : Do you know one thing ????? ............... You are awesome , thanx for the info man

Comment: It might not be the best idea to put your private email address open to the internet unless you like spam.

Comment: @LoganDam : whoooops ....... thnx ,will remove right away

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to check if an email address actually exists is to send an email to it and let the user respond on that.

For example:

- a confirmation code that needs to be filled in your website
- a link, going to your website, that needs to be visited

And still it is uncertain whether the email is existing afterwards, as it is easy to simply create a temporary email to pass the validation and delete it afterwards.

Instead of validating email addresses you can use the Google API to let your users sign in using their account. It is also possible to use OpenID on a similar way.

Comment: yeah thanx man ..... i think this might be my ultimate ans , but actually i was expecting , may be there is some web service which does it so , that is why i happened to ask , thanx

Comment: can you please provide a link or tutorial for Google open ID which you think is very much useful ???

Comment: check this for google open id: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't possible using existing services and/or API's, since it could be quite a security risk. Use an email with a validation link if you want to be sure the address exists. Or OpenID, as mentioned by BalusC.