# Regular expression not working, what does ?=. mean

Tags: regex

hi i a beginner in working with regular expressions i have a regular expression for email as i have copied that from some other source

```
(?=.[@])
```

it is not working i wanted to test different combinations so i m trying to match only @ value for the input field but is not working.
if i write the same to the numerical values it is working in the password field

```
((?=.[0-9]+).{6,})
```

***Note:***As i am practicing application of different methods and trying to get a clear idea about regex please ignore the common ethics like the password regex i chose.

Moreover i wanted to know why this `?=.` used preceding the pattern

Thanks in advance

Comment: ?=. is positive lookahead

Comment: Thanks @samgak can you give some references to learn about the usage of regular expressions

Comment: You can use this to test regexes: http://www.regexr.com/ You can paste a regex in and then hover over each part with the mouse to see what it does. The cheatsheet section also gives a good summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex expressions are not doing what you think:

**Email:**

```
(?=.[@])
<!-- matches a single character followed by @, e.g. a@ -->
```

**Password:**

```
((?=.[0-9]+).{6,})
<!-- matches a single character followed by at least 5 digits, e.g. a12345 -->
```

You could try using this for email: `(?=.*[@].*\..*)`
And this for password: `((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})`

Comment: Thanks @Tim can you give me any references to learn about usage of regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  [Email validation using regular expression in JSF 2 / PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875108/email-validation-using-regular-expression-in-jsf-2-primefaces)

```
[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]
```