# email validation shows validatorMessage twice

Tags: jsf, primefaces, validation

I used email validation.But it shows validatorMessage twice.How can i solve this problem?

```
<p:inputText size="30" id="epostaAdresi" value="#{kullaniciBean.email}"                                
validatorMessage="my message" maxlength="100" title="test@example.com">
<f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: Problem is caused elsewhere than visible in the information provided so far. Please post a true SSCCE. By the way, food for thought: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824163

Comment: Where is the `<h:messages/>`?

Comment: @kolossus there is no like this." validatorMessage="my message"  "this is the message which shows twice.

Comment: Do you still get 2 same messages when you remove `validatorMessage`? Or do you now finally get 2 different messages whereby the second gives a hint as to which kind of other validation was been performed on the same input?

Comment: @Deniz - what I'm looking for is anywhere you've set `showSummary` and `showDetail` to `true`.

Comment: @BalusC when i remove validatormessage,there are two different messages like "Regex Pattern not matched" and other message comes from my POJO like "email is not valid.please check." Can i remove "Regex Pattern not matched" message??

Comment: @Deniz - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7416985/1530938